# What's going on with the number next to the "review" link?

Tags: bug

On the bar on top, there is a number immediately to the left of the "review" link (at the moment 5); it has pop-up text "5 total posts awaiting review". Yet when I click on the review link (or on the number), all the queues show 0 as the number of questions/posts/answers/edits awaiting review.

Do other people have the same experience, and if so, does anyone know what's going on?

Comment: See a similar post, [What is with that orange box?](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/16857/what-is-with-that-orange-box/16858#16858) on MSE meta. No you are not alone, it appears to be a site wide thing. [Here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/17061/phantom-suggested-edits) is yet another discuss on the same phenomenon. It has been that way ever since the feature has existed to my recollection.

Comment: Ahh on Meta SE, a better source: [Please dim the color of the review task counter when...](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/231051/please-dim-the-color-of-the-review-task-counter-when-there-are-no-actionable-tas).

Comment: If someone want's to put that into an answer for us that would be great, I have to go to some sort of Christmas party/function.

Comment: @J.W.Perry Enjoy. I'm working on an answer.

Comment: @HDE226868 Thank's kindly. :)))

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've had it for a while (it seems to only come up after you pass a certain rep limit, though, which might be 2K for beta sites) and it's annoying. I see the "5", too, and, for anyone who's too lazy to follow J.W.Perry's links (how dare you!), it represents the total number of posts awaiting review - even posts you've already reviewed but still need reviews from others. The reason it exists is that it's way too expensive to individualize it, given the number of users network-wide who have the necessary rep.

I say "annoying" because it hasn't disappeared for at least a week (if not more), meaning that **we need reviewers!** Please, guys, if you can, go through the queues.